# Bind 9 - Secondary Zone File only updates after restart

Tags: bind

a quick description of my setup. the primary zone is running on a windows server dns. the secondary zone is runnung on bind. if i delete the zone file and restart bind the transfer works fine. means the zone file will be created with the latest entrys. if now add or remove an entry on the windows server the bind log says:

```
named[18697]: zone xxx.xxx/IN: transferred serial 144
named[18697]: transfer of 'xxx.xxx/IN' from 192.168.111.4#53: Transfer completed: 1 messages, 5 records, 212 bytes, 0.109 secs (1944 bytes/sec)
named[18697]: zone xxx.xxx/IN: sending notifies (serial 144)
```

but the zone file is not updated! if i remove the file again and restart bind i will get the updated records. 
Anyone a idea whats my problem here? thank you!

Comment: Is the question specifically about the zone *file* not being updated immediately or about the zone contents? (Ie, is there any real problem?)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat speculative until it's confirmed if the question is specifically about the zone file rather than the zone contents.

BIND does not immediately write data from zone transfers (for slave zones) or updates (for dynamically updated zones) into the zone file proper, instead it  buffers the changes in the journal file (`.jnl`) for the time being and periodically flushes all changes to the main zone file.

This does not in any way affect what data is being served; the new data is served regardless of whether it has been merged into the main zone file yet or not.

Additionally, current BIND versions by default do not even use the human-friendly text-based [*master file format*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5) for slave zones in favor of more efficient binary formatting (no actual downside as you're not working directly with the files for slave zones anyway).

The lesson to be learned from all this is that you shouldn't really be looking at the file contents in cases where the file is managed by BIND but instead look at what data it serves.

If you, for whatever reason, must look at the file contents instead of querying the running `named` process you will want to read the file in a way that also takes the journal into account.

Eg `named-compilezone -j -o - example.com db.example.com`

(Alternatively `named-compilezone -f raw -j -o - example.com db.example.com` if the file is in *raw* (binary) format.)